# Deployment size for Linux vs Windows

Tags: qt, deployment, qml

I'm deploying an app developed by Qt for both Windows and Linux:

On Windows I'm using built-in Qt `windeployqt` tool:

```
windeployqt.exe app.exe --qmldir %NS_REPO_DIR%\qml\
```

On Linux I'm using [linuxdeployqt](https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt):

```sh
linuxdeployqt_EXE="${NS_REPO_DIR}/scripts/linuxdeployqt/linuxdeployqt-7-x86_64.AppImage"

${linuxdeployqt_EXE} app -qmake=${NS_QT_QMAKE_EXE} -qmldir=${NS_REPO_DIR}/qml/
```

The deployment size for Windows is around 70 MB and for Linux is around 300 MB. Is it normal? Is there anything I might be missing?

Thanks!

#### Update

This is my deployment on Linux whose content is sorted by size. The Qt files don't look like to be `debug` mode. Also, there is a huge `libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5.12.7` file of 111 MB:

[image: Deployment archive]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would have to blame here to all the GNU/Linux distributions makers for changing so many things.

Unlike Windows that there are only few version Windows 7,8, 10 and that is it. In GNU/Linux we have so many versions and variants that we have to include "almost" everything that an application needs to ensure it will run on the majority of the existent system variants.

Said that, you can manually check the files deployed in your AppDir manually and remove those you know that your application will not require.

Side note: While linuxdeployqt is still functional there are other tools that do a better job. Consider checking https://github.com/linuxdeploy/ and https://github.com/AppImageCrafters/appimage-builder